# Thread needs to wait a list is updated

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The class below updates a map in particluar interval of time.

```
public class CheckerThread extends Thread {

   private volatile HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

   @Override
   public void run() {
           while (true) {
                updateMap();
           try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
           catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // Do something
            }
          }
    }

  private void updateMap() {
   HashMap<String, Integer> localMap = new HashMap<>();
   int count = 0;
     while (count < 10) {
        localMap.put(count + "a", count);
      count++;
     }
        this.map = localMap;
   }


   public Map<String, Integer> getMap() {
    return this.map;
   }
}
```

The Class below calls the method getMap() to get the Map . I need to ensure the list is fully updated before returning the map in the class "CheckerThread". The method should wait till map  is updated.

```
public class GetterThread extends Thread {

 private final CheckerThread checkerThread;

 public GetterThread(final CheckerThread checkerThread) {
    this.checkerThread = checkerThread;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
       System.err.println(this.checkerThread.getMap());
    }
  }
```

Another class Main creates threads.

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws   InterruptedException {
  int i = 0;
  GetterThread[] getterThreads = new GetterThread[5];
  CheckerThread checkerThread = new CheckerThread();
  checkerThread.start();
   while (i < 5) {
      getterThreads[i] = new GetterThread(checkerThread);
      getterThreads[i].start();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
       i++;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does the answer have to use custom classes or can you use classes from Java's standard API?  (Also, never catch and ignore `InterruptedException`.)

Comment: You never increment your `count` variable in your `updateMap` method, it will run forever

Comment: This is not the actual code . This is just the overview of functionality. So ignore the count and exception.Anyways thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a threading is ok for that but not enough (most of them because threads don't return anything after they do the job...) if you want to still work with threads then you will end in a wait/join/notify approach...

you can instead of a `thread --> runnable` use a `task --> callable`,

**Callables** are threads on steroids, you can execute them in a **ExecutorService** and wait until the job is done getting even a result that let you know if everything went ok or not!!

take this as an example and consult the doc for more information:

- [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
- [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)
- [Callabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

```
public class _Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(new MapCleaner());
        exService.execute(futureTask);
        System.out.println("Was everything ok??: " + futureTask.get());
    }
}

class MapCleaner implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Futures? Future.get() waits for task to get completed. Could this be what you need?

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Map<String, Integer>> {

    private volatile HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean wait = true;

    public void call() {
        while (wait) {
            updateMap();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private void updateMap() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> localMap = new HashMap<>();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 10) {
            localMap.put(count + "a", count);
        }
        this.map = localMap;
        wait = false;
    }

}
```

and just call the future

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Map<String, Integer>> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable());
// Future.get() waits for task to get completed
Map<String, Integer> myMap = fut.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I think you should be using a `BlockingQueue`.  Put elements into the queue in your "checker" thread, and read them with a blocking wait in the "getter" thread.  This is easy and pretty clean, not too many changes are needed.

A queue will solve not only synchronization problems for you but also *timing* problems.  No matter which order your threads run, your getter thread always waits until data is available, then returns.  It's pretty much bomb proof.

BTW you have a bug in your checker thread.  You put ten elements into the map, but you never increment `count`, so that loop never exits (it puts an infinite number of elements into the map, you'll get an out of memory error eventually).

Also, never ever catch and ignore `InterruptedException`.  You almost always want to exit your thread if you get interrupted.  C.f. Brian Goetz's book *Java Concurrency in Practice* for more.

```
public class SimpleThreading
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      MainThread.main(args);
   }
}

class MainThread extends Thread
{

   public static void main( final String[] args )
           throws InterruptedException
   {
      int i = 0;
      GetterThread[] getterThreads = new GetterThread[ 5 ];
      CheckerThread checkerThread = new CheckerThread();
      checkerThread.start();
      while( i < 5 ) {
         getterThreads[i] = new GetterThread( checkerThread );
         getterThreads[i].start();
         Thread.sleep( 1000 );
         i++;
      }
   }
}

class GetterThread extends Thread
{

   private final CheckerThread checkerThread;

   public GetterThread( final CheckerThread checkerThread )
   {
      this.checkerThread = checkerThread;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      try {
         System.out.println("waiting..." + checkerThread.getQueue() );
         System.err.println( this.checkerThread.getQueue().take() );
      } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
         // exit on interrupt
      }
   }
}

class CheckerThread extends Thread
{

   private HashMap<String, Integer> map;
   private final BlockingQueue<Map<String,Integer>> queue =
           new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      while( true )
         try {
            updateMap();
            queue.put( map );
            System.out.println( "Added " + map );
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
         } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            return; // exit on interrupt
         }
   }

   private void updateMap()
   {
      HashMap<String, Integer> localMap = new HashMap<>();
      int count = 0;
      while( count < 10 )
         localMap.put( count + "a", count++ );
      this.map = localMap;
   }

   public BlockingQueue<Map<String, Integer>> getQueue()
   {
      return queue;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not the actual code . This is just the overview of functionality. So ignore the count and exception.Anyways thanks for the correction.